# phpMyAdmin, When Inserting it displayes no fields

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I Don't know if it's a phpMyAdmin problem or it's a problem with my MYSQL server.
It happens to me in every database , whenever I want to insert data.
Picture (I don't have a 10+ Reputation, So here's a link): https://i.stack.imgur.com/laiei.png

Thanks for helping :)

-------------------> EDIT <----------------------

**I Found The Fix By myself, Thanks to @PriestVallon, I couldn't do it without him.**

If anyone want's to know the fix, 
GO TO CMD, cd to your MYSQL Folder and then to bin:

```
cd C:/Program Files/Zend/MYSQL51/bin/
```

(For Example).
Now, shut down the server and start it (Restart):

```
mysqladmin -u username -p shutdown
```

(Replace username with your username, you will be asked to type in your password when executing the command).

Now, start MySQL service:

```
mysqld
```

(You can close the CMD tab, The service will keep running).

~ The Problem was that I needed to restart the server. Thanks again, @PriestVallon.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the structure of the database?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nnXkI.png It's empty too, IDK why.
- Running on Zend.

Comment: What happens if you type in "DESCRIBE adminhelp" into the SQL tab?

Comment: It says: #1 - Can't create/write to file 'X:\XXXX XXXX\XXX\MySQL51\data\art\#sql16e4_eb_0.MYI' (Errcode: 2) , Is it a permission problem? what should I do?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 8 Release Preview , btw: I changed the sentence.

Comment: Try using this, ICACLS "X:\XXXX XXXX\XXX\MySQL51\data\art\#sql16e4_eb_0.MYI" /grant "Users":F

Comment: Umm.. it says: C:\Program Files\Zend\MySQL51\data\art\#sql16e4_eb_0.MYI: The system cannot find
 the path specified. - What should I do now?

Comment: Please move your answer to an actual answer.